# Can someone demystify EMR/EC2/Lambda/SNS/SQ in AWS services for me?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a reason for this question. So I would appreciate positive responses.
AWS is a black box to me.
In my mind all services offered by AWS are plug play. So AWS has a user interface where you register a bunch of info and you click a button and AWS takes care of it.
But clearly that's not the case because there are AWS services based interview questions.
So I am not sure if there is a coding element to it. Can someone demystify AWS and all its services on a higher level to me ?
Like AWS EMR/EC2/Lambda/SNS/SQS - Just a one word response is fine. Right now to me its a button clicking services with zero coding or skill. But clearly I am wrong.

Comment: Why not check docs for these services? They explain pretty well what they do.

Comment: I stumbled upon this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html but this looks like a "how to create gmail account" type manual. It so dry and verbose

Comment: Learn to use the AWS CLI to create and read the resources, and it will no longer be a black box. Also, check out CloudFormation. It is a way to create AWS resources via JSON code. Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVK8ultk-u0&t=143s

Comment: [Amazon Web Services In Plain English](https://expeditedsecurity.com/aws-in-plain-english/)

Comment: AWS has a learning path: AWS Cloud Practitionner, Architect Associate, Developper, Sysadmin... You should follow it. You cannot jump from "this is a black box" to "I understand clearly", specially if the docs is too "dry" for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now to me its a button clicking services with zero coding or skill. But clearly I am wrong.

I'm going to assume that your question is something along the lines of why they're called "web services", rather than what each service does. If the latter, then you've gotten a lot of links in the comments. I'd also Google for Amazon's Cloud Practitioner videos.

The reason why AWS is called a web service is because that's exactly how they work: when you want to do something, you make a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE to the endpoint for a service. For example, to send a message to an SQS queue in the us-east-1 region, you make a POST request to `https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`.

Each of these requests is [signed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html), using an access key and secret key. If you don't properly sign a request, it will be rejected.

While you can construct these GET and POST requests yourself, AWS provides a bunch of language-specific SDKs that do it for you. For example, if you want to send a message to an SQS queue using Java, you would write something like this:

```
AmazonSQS client = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient()

// this is available from the console, or you could make another call to retrieve it if you know the queue name
String myQueueUrl = "...";

client.sendMessage(myQueueUrl, "an example message");
```